# Transaction Scope in Pub/Sub + Message Label in Rebus

Tags: rebus

Currently I'm using WCF as service bus. But I want to switch to a more powerful service bus. I Chose Rebus.
I'm somehow new to Rebus. I have some problems :

1) My data is persisted in a DB table. I want publisher to read all persisted data every n seconds and publishes it to subscribers and then set a sent flag to data in DB. 
Is there some timing for publishing? 
Reading and publishing and changing (setting flag) data must be done in a transaction scope. Is there any defined solution in Rebus?

2) In Consumer, I want to save published data in some table. Reading message from message queue and saving in DB (in my handler) must be done in transaction scope. How Rebus do this?

3) Message label for published messages set to a random unique string. I want to set my custom label for created MSMQ message. is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are on your own when it comes to querying database tables at regular intervals – there's no built-in mechanism in Rebus that does this.

I can recommend you take a look at [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) or something similar.

2) You can enable automatic transaction scopes in your Rebus handlers by using the [`Rebus.TransactionScopes`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.TransactionScopes) package.

3) Out of the box, it is not possible to specify the label to be used on the MSMQ message. It will be set by Rebus to a string consisting of the message type and ID as indicated by [this extension method](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Bus/MessageExtensions.cs#L114-L135).